# How to properly debug XMLRPC fails

Tags: ubuntu, scheduled-task, xmlrpc

I have an Odoo instance runing on Ubuntu server and I want to query the XMLRPC api from a Windows machine in the same subnet. The two can normally communicate and it all works ok, but if I set the client script to run every 5 minutes in Windows Scheduler it starts to experience problems.

> socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

If I wait for some short time, disable the Scheduled Task and I don't touch the script it starts working again, but only for a few calls, then the error comes back.

So for some reason the Ubuntu machine is denying if there are too many calls. I just can find out on which level these rules are. I don't use firewall.

```
root@oddo9:~$ ufw status
Status: inactive 
root@oddo9:~$
```

Also no iptables

```
root@oddo9:~$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source    
destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               
destination
```

There's also no output from Odoo, so I have no idea how to debug this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered what was wrong. We had two machines with the same IP in our subnet so there was the conflict. Client was trying to connect to some other machine, which did not even listen for XMLRPC protocol.

I thought that it works if I wait let's say 15 minutes, but no.. it just randomly worked for a call or two. It all makes sense now.